# Probability of drawing 3 blue marbles in consecutive order

Tags: probability

I have a bag with 30 coloured marbles. Some colours are repeated.

1. Blue (x3)
2. Yellow (x2)
3. Red (x2)
4. Orange (x2)
5. Other colours (x21, a different colour each)

I've been asked to draw all the marbles out of the bag (without replacement). What's the probability that I'll draw 3 blue marbles consecutively once I start? So,

> blue, blue, blue, other colours ...

Comment: with or without replacement?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... but once you draw a ball, that's it. Can't put it back.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton  What you described is without replacement.

Comment: Are you asking what the probability is that the first three marbles selected are blue or the probability that as you draw marbles from the bag that the three blue marbles will be drawn consecutively?

Comment: Sorry, I made a hash of the question. I've tried to clarify it. Let me know if I can improve it further.

Answer (score 2):

Your probability of drawing a blue ball on your first try is $\frac{3}{30}$. Once you throw that ball away, there are $2$ blue balls left, out of $29$ total balls left. Thus you have a $\frac{2}{29}$ probability of your second ball being blue, conditional on your first ball being blue. Once you throw that away, there is only one blue ball left, out of $28$ total balls. Thus your probability of your third ball being blue, conditional on your first two balls being blue, is $\frac{1}{28}$. So all in all, your probability on your first three balls being blue is 
$$
\frac{3}{30}\frac{2}{29}\frac{1}{28}=\frac{1}{4060}
$$

Comment: If we just need to calculate the possibility of having 3 FIRST blue balls, your answer is correct.

Comment: @anhldbk are you implying I misread the question or are you just restating my last sentence? This seems to be what the OP wanted

Comment: Yep, I just restated your last sentence. Never mind!

Answer (score 2):

That's called without replacement.

One approach is as follows.
There are 3 blue ($B$)marbles in the bag, and 27 non blue ($N$).

You already know that one the first draw, the probability of selecting a $B$ is $$\frac{3}{30}$$.

On you next draw, there are only 2 $B$ left with 29 total.
So the probability of selecting a $B$ is
$$\frac{2}{29}.$$

Similarly, there is a $\frac{1}{28}$ chance of selecting a $B$ on the third draw. So the probability of interest is
$$\frac{3\cdot2\cdot1}{30\cdot29\cdot28} = \frac{1}{4060}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_i$ the ball you get at the $i-$drawing, then
$$
\begin{align}
P(x_1 = B, x_2 = B, x_3 = B) &= P(x_1 = B \wedge x_2 = B \wedge x_3 = B)\\
&= P(x_1 = B) \cdot P(x_2 = B) \cdot P(x_3 = B)\\
&= \frac{\text{blue balls}}{\text{total balls}} \cdot \frac{\text{remaining blue balls}}{\text{remaining balls}} \cdot \frac{\text{remaining blue balls}}{\text{remaining balls}}\\
&= \frac{3}{30}\cdot\frac{2}{29\cdot}\frac{1}{28}\\
&=\frac{1}{4060}\\
&\approx 0.000246305
\end{align}$$